# Android RatingBar shows extra remainder

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I'm using the standard Android RatingBar. It seems to behave quite weird. For some reason I can't select only full stars. It always shows a little bit more or less. Also the .setNumStars property doesn't seem to work. I'm using the following code:

```
RatingBar ratingbar = new RatingBar(this);
ratingbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
ratingbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ratingbar.setNumStars(5);
ratingbar.setStepSize(1);
ratingbar.setRating(1);
linearLayoutReviews.addView(ratingbar);
```

When I select 1 star it selects one star:

When I select 2 stars:

[image]

When I select 3 stars:

[image]

When I select 4 stars:

[image]

And when I select 5 stars:

[image]

So for some reason it shows more than 5 stars, and there will always be a remainder of the next star selected

**EDIT**

When I set .setNumStars to 6 I can select them one by one, but than ofcourse, I have six

**EDIT**

This is the xml of the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutReviews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by making a new linearlayout and placing it below the old linearlayout. I added the ratingbar to the new linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

You have added  `RatingBar` multiple times `LinearLayout` that's why its showing previous `RatingBar` in your `LinearLayout` .

So remove all current `RatingBar` from `LinearLayout` first and then add new `RatingBar`.

I have added one line in your code  see below: it may help you:

```
RatingBar ratingbar = new RatingBar(this);
ratingbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
ratingbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ratingbar.setNumStars(5);
ratingbar.setStepSize(1);
ratingbar.setRating(1);
//In your code add the lines given below
linearLayoutReviews.removeAllViews();
linearLayoutReviews.addView(ratingbar);
```

Comment: You're right, I have multiple ratingbars in my LinearLayout, but I need them to stay. Is there any other way?

Comment: so you should change your `LinearLayout`  orientation Horizontal to Vertical. All Rating bars are shown one by one.

Comment: thank you for your response, but the LinearLayout orientation already is vertical, I've added the xml